# Updating values in mongoDB collection using Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to mongoDB and and I found out how to insert and retrieve values in mongoDB using Node JS. When I retrieve values from collection, I get the values as below.

`[{"1":["muthu","Pandiyan"],"_id":"5d7a23cdeee1c2ca3bf52a76"},{"2":["muthu","raj","ram","rifas"],"_id":"5d7a23cdeee1c2ca3bf52a77"},{"3":["pandiyan","jeni","raj"],"_id":"5d7a23cdeee1c2ca3bf52a78"}]`

I would want to update values in the array of key `"1"` as `["muthu","Pandiyan","newuser"]` and I tried the following code but I am not getting the desired result. I feel that I am doing the mistake in first parameter of the updatedOne query. Please correct me where I am missing.

`var r = yield db.collection('dummy3qa').updateOne({"1"},{$addToSet:"newuser"});
assert.equal(null, err);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. 
Refer this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

```
db.dummy3qa.update(
   {'1'},
   { $addToSet:"newuser"}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work `db.dummy3qa.update(_id:5d7a23cdeee1c2ca3bf52a76,{$addToSet:{1 : "newuser"});`. why yours did not work is because you are not specifying where it should update. Mongo needs to know where it should update, that is first and secondly you made a mistake in your `$addToSet`. why because from the doc you specify key and value as you update eg. `{$addToSet: {key: value}}`. for more in info `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/`

Comment: I dont want to update the values based on _id, but want to update the value if the key is "1".

Comment: I think this will work for you db.collection('dummy3qa').updateOne("1",{$addToSet:{1 : "newuser"} );